# How to create CRON for delete 'Core.XXXX' file from cPanel

Tags: php, magento, cron, cpanel

I have e-Commerce store built and run on Magento.

From last few months files are automatically created (around 500mb size). It fill server storage and site down again n again.

I have already posted one question to stop generating a Core.XXXX file but no solution : [Magento automatically generate “core.XXXXX” file in server](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87760/magento-automatically-generate-core-xxxxx-file-in-server)

So, for now i want to automatically delete those file by setting up a cron job.

You have any idea how to setup?

Thank you.!

Comment: can you use linux or any other ?

Comment: This is a server management question, not a programming question. Magento doesn't cause core dumps as such, Apache, mysql usually are the issue, php should be creating stack traces not core dumps. Fix the server problem and it will go away. Determine what's core dumping and ask in the appropriate server management section to get an answer. As to creating a cron job to fix a symptom, try possibly superuser.stackexchange.

Comment: @FiascoLabs First thank you for the information. I was already contact hosting providers and He said It's not a server problem bcoz primary domain works fine on the same folder and this is subdomain inside that folder. Ex. : `/public_html/Website` is the main hosted domain and magento installed in `/public_html/Website/subdomain`. Core.XXXX file created inside that `subdomain` folder.

Answer (score 0):

create one function put your delete file code into it and set cron on your server with url and call it every specific time.

to know more information about cronjob please check this url :

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: This is another way.. but i want to remove/delete file through Cron job setup only. Thank you!

Comment: i gave link to know about how to set cronjob not that way but you need to create your code in one page or function and set that url into your server using cronjob its run every define time by you and delete your files.